# Vaadin Grid how to wrap long text in columns

Tags: java, grid, vaadin

I have a Vaadin grid with 7 columns:

```
Grid grid = new Grid<>();
grid.setSizeFull();

grid.addColumn(User::getUserName).setCaption("Name").setExpandRatio(2);
grid.addColumn(User::getLastName).setCaption("Last Name").setExpandRatio(1);                    
grid.addColumn(User::getAge).setCaption("Age").setExpandRatio(2);
grid.addColumn(User::getWork).setCaption("Work").setExpandRatio(1);
grid.addColumn(User::getJobTitle).setCaption("Job Title").setExpandRatio(1);
grid.addColumn(User::getSalary).setCaption("Salary").setExpandRatio(1);
grid.addColumn(User::getOther).setCaption("Other").setExpandRatio(1);
```

What I need is to set columns width in a way - that all 7 will have be shown on a screen. 
With my code now it works in a way that if text content of any column cell is very long - the last columns are not shown on the screen and screen must be scrolled horizontally.

I tried to use method `setWidth()` and as it takes value in pixels the grid view may differ on various browsers and screens.

What I need is to be sure that my grid looks the same way on different screens and with different cell values.

Comment: Your problem is not column expand ratio is how to wrap text around.

Comment: Could you please specify it more?

Comment: If the text is short the expandRatio holds, it is working. If the text is too long, the expand ratio breaks. Try to play with the height of the cells to see if it helps

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change cell's height. I've tried to use overflow:hidden but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I had the same situation, this was my solution:

Grid configuration

```
Grid<Item> gridItem = new Grid<>();
gridItem.setRowHeight(50.0);
```

Column configuration

```
gridItem.addComponentColumn(item -> {
            Label label = new Label();
            label.setValue(item.getText());
            label.setWidthUndefined();
            label.setStyleName(ValoTheme.LAYOUT_HORIZONTAL_WRAPPING);
            return label;
        })
        .setCaption("Item")
        .setWidth(380.0);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Also useful to call setHandleWidgetEvents(true) on the column if you want the row to be selectable when clicking a widget.